# Compare values of multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's say I have four columns with strings in each column (pandas df).
If I want to compare if they are all the same, I came up with something like this:

```
df['same_FB'] = np.where( (df['FB_a'] == df['FB_b']) & (df['FB_a'] == df['FB_c']) & (df['FB_a'] == df['FB_d']), 1,0)
```

It works fine, but it doesn't look good and if I had to add a fifth or sixth column it get's even uglier.
Is there another way to test if all columns are the same?
Alternatively, I would be ok with counting the distinct values in these four columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)** + **[`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)**:

```
x,*y = ['FB_a', 'FB_b', 'Fb_c', 'FB_d']
df['same_FB'] = df[y].eq(df[x], axis=0).all(1).view('i1')
```

Alternatively you can use `nunique`:

```
c = ['FB_a', 'FB_b', 'Fb_c', 'FB_d']
df['same_FB'] = df[c].nunique(axis=1, dropna=False).eq(1).view('i1')
```

Example:

```
print(df)

    A  B  C  D  E
0  10  1  1  1  1
1  20  2  2  2  2
2  30  3  3  3  3
3  40  4  4  4  4

x,*y = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df['same'] = df[y].eq(df[x], axis=0).all(1).view('i1')

print(df)

    A  B  C  D  E  same
0  10  1  1  1  1     1
1  20  2  2  2  2     1
2  30  3  3  3  3     1
3  40  4  4  4  4     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works, but also I would like to understand it. What does the '1' do inside all()? Why do you need that?

Comment: @cvluepke It specify the condition if all values along **`axis=1`** are truthy. For more clarity you can write it as **`.all(axis=1)`**..

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use chained python logic. Here is the code:

```
df['same_FB'] = np.where((df['FB_a'] == df['FB_b'] == df['FB_c'] == df['FB_d']), 1,0)
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes it look less complex.